# Excel: alternatives for very long IF($Cell=key, value) list?

Tags: excel, arraylist, excel-formula

I have formula which looks something like the following:

`=(IF(ISBLANK(B1),1, (IF($B1="Banana", 2.23, IF($B1="Cherry",3.5))) )*C1*A1)`

Here the value of the cell B1 is being pulled from a data validation drop-down list, which unlike the example above is getting very, very long, with many IF and OR operators. Its quickly going to become impossible for me to declare maintain the relationship of all the bannans and cherries in the formula it self. What's the point of updating both the list AND the formula with largely the same information - just to give the user a dropdown :/

One option would be for me put the multiplier value in with the drop down list and then use `VALUE(RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND("x",B1))` [to pull it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337723/explode-a-cells-value-and-multiply-together-values-found-on-either-side-of-a-se#comment13316668_10337723). BUT in this case the multiplier is a very long decimal and would be confusing to the end user, like: "Banana 0.000000d325001"

I see two possibilities:

1.Find a way to hide the multiplier from being displayed to the user in the drop down menu with some sort of preprocessing OR

2. Find a way to associate the bananas and cherries in some sort of array Key : Value relationship that wont display in the dropdown menu.

Does anyone know how this might be achieved - is it feasible or just a world of hurt?

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Have you thought of using `VLOOKUP()` for that "array Key : Value relationship"?

Comment: dead new to Excel so wasn't aware of VLOOKUP() but after looing at the help im not sure I understand. Can I use it with the named list I have set up - putting the value for 'banana' in an adjacent column?

Comment: ok so I think I understand it better. - but this still means I have to know the lookup and column values and insert them into the formula. Im realising that I want something dynamic. Just as when I add a value to the list, and it appears as an option in the dropdown -- I dont want to have to update the formula for the new lookup values as well. I want the formula to see the user chose "Bananas" and know to search column "A" for "Bananas" and then look in the adjacent cell for the value. Is that possible? Im starting to search for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just need one table with your fruit/price info, then your lookup and validation follow that table.

[image: Screen capture of Excel spreadsheet showing VLOOKUP formula and data]

Now that I see your second comment, the problem is a little trickier. I would use a Named Range. Instead of using `=VLOOKUP(B1,G$1:H$3,2,FALSE)`, use `=VLOOKUP(B1,FruitTable,2,FALSE)`.

`FruitTable` is a named range. You can create a named range by selecting `G1:H3`, then typing `FruitTable` in the box to the left of the formula bar (in the picture above, this is the box with "C1" inside it; if you click in that box, it will let you type a name).

You can also use this "named range" technique for your validation menu, except you will want to select just `G1:G3` and give it a different name, such as `FruitList`. Then, when you set up the validation, use `=FruitList` for the Source.

Now, when you add new items to your list, you just have to adjust your named range (using Formulas/Name Manager).

Comment: If you insert new items to your list *inbetween* other values, your named range is automatically adjusted. Using a dummy item as a list "delimiter" can also be useful in this case.

Comment: Many many thanks everyone for your help - I've been able to cobble together a working document from your great examples. DanM - Brilliant explanation. Just what I needed to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
=(IF(ISBLANK(B1), 1, VLOOKUP(B1,YOUR_NAMED_RANGE,2,FALSE)*C1*A1)
```

Where YOUR_NAMED_RANGE is a two-column named range containing Banana, Cherry, etc in Col1 and multipliers in Col2